# use custom mapping in reverse map

Tags: .net, api, asp.net-core, automapper

This is my code:

```cs
public class PostDto : BaseDto<PostDto, Post>
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public override int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Html)]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int TimeToRead { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    public string Image { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public DateTimeOffset Time { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public override void CustomMappings(IMappingExpression<Post, PostDto> mappingExpression)
    {
            mappingExpression.ForMember(
               dest => dest.Time,
               config => config.MapFrom(src => DateTimeOffset.Now));

            mappingExpression.ReverseMap().ForMember(
                dest => dest.Time,
                config => config.MapFrom(src => DateTimeOffset.Now));

            mappingExpression
                .ForMember(d => d.Time, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => DateTimeOffset.Now))
                .ReverseMap()
                .ForMember(d => d.Time, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => DateTimeOffset.Now))
                .ForPath(s => s.Time, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => DateTimeOffset.Now));
     }
}
```

And I get dto from controller, and map it to entity. I want to add Time when mapping Automatically but it's not work.
If I map from entity(post) to dto(postDto) for example to convert date to string, it's work but in reverse it's not work

my Controller:

```cs
public override Task<ApiResult<PostSelectDto>> Create(PostDto dto, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Code to convert dto to entity(after map time in [model] is null or default value of datetimeoffset)

```cs
var model = dto.ToEntity(Mapper);
```

ToEntity method:

```cs
public TEntity ToEntity(IMapper mapper)
{
    return mapper.Map<TEntity>(CastToDerivedClass(mapper, this));
}
```

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration-validation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this url we can add datetime like code that I send with override
[link](http://blog.mark-mann.co.uk/index.php/2011/08/automapper-tip-datetime-and-usevalue-dont-mix/)

Reason is because, UseValue is a static, so it’s set once when the MapProfile is instantiated and all subsequent .Map() invokes will use the same static value

So I write custom map without use reflection to create map for entities and dto

```
public class PostCustomMapping : IHaveCustomMapping
{
    public void CreateMappings(Profile profile)
    {
        profile.CreateMap<Post, PostDto>().ReverseMap()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Time,
                opt =>
                    opt.MapFrom(src => DateTimeOffset.Now))

            .ForMember(dest => dest.Text,
                opt =>
                    opt.MapFrom(src => src.Text.FixPersianChars()))

            .ForMember(dest => dest.Title,
                opt =>
                    opt.MapFrom(src => src.Title.FixPersianChars()))

            .ForMember(dest => dest.ShortDescription,
                opt =>
                    opt.MapFrom(src => src.ShortDescription.FixPersianChars()));
    }
}
```

Comment: About `FixPersianChars`, check value transformers. You don't have to specify it everywhere :)

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I check just when I get that value from user, forexample in create new post

Comment: You can always establish some rule and then use that. There's no need to do it by hand.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Thanks, Can you give me some example?

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/UnitTests/ValueTransformers.cs